# How to Set Multiple Cursors in VSCode at Each RegEx Find Result

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, azure-data-studio

Today I wanted to edit all stops in a SQL INSERT that followed a Regex pattern. I realized that if I could use the [multi cursor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_multi-cursor-selection) feature in Visual Studio Code I could make a ton of changes all at one time.

For instance, in the following SQL

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Location] (key, longName, shortName, oldRegion, contactId, email, city, state, zip, isActive)
VALUES
('GEORG','Georgian College','GEORG','1A','1271','globalint@school.edu','Barrie','ON','L4M 3X9','1'),
('LOYAL','Loyalist College','LOYAL','2A','1271','globalint@school.edu','Belleville','ON','K8N 5B9','0')
-- etc.
```

the `contactId` and `isActive` weren't really varchars, and I could find them with a regex of `'\d+'`, but I couldn't figure out how to set the cursors to each spot with keyboard commands or shortcuts. How would you do this?

Comment: `Alt+Enter` is the easiest way to do this.  Enter your find text and the `Alt+Enter` will select them all (no need to change focus from the findwidget).

Comment: @mark thanks, that's slick. I'll post this shorter version of steps in the answer too.

Answer (score 87):

#### How to Place Multiple Cursors at the End of All Your RegEx Finds

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is what you're after (Thanks to **Mark**).

To find this or similar keybindings open the [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) and search for `findWidget` for commands used with `CTRL` + `F`, or `searchViewlet` for commands used with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F`.

These [keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) are useful for both VSCode and [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio) and can be customized.

#### Full Example for Your Case

For your example, you could do this through the following keyboard commands:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Find)
2. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (`toggleFindRegex` command)
3. `'\d+'` (what to look for)
4. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (add cursors; `editor.action.selectAllMatches` command)

**-OR-**

4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (add cursors; `editor.action.selectHighlights` command)
5. <kbd>ESC</kbd> (`closeFindWidget` command)

Now the following text should have four blinking cursors (at the daggers ), where you can edit to your s content!

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Location] (key, longName, shortName, oldRegion, contactId, email, city, state, zip, isActive)
VALUES
('GEORG','Georgian College','GEORG','1A','1271','globalint@school.edu','Barrie','ON','L4M 3X9','1'),
('LOYAL','Loyalist College','LOYAL','2A','1271','globalint@school.edu','Belleville','ON','K8N 5B9','0')
-- etc.
```

Comment: This is amazingly helpful, thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much, This saved me a lot of time trying to select multiple words manually

Comment: Is crazy how this little combination has saved me hours of work. Awesome.

Comment: You may also want to check this vscode extension out. Combining with the multiple-cursor, you can generate and do some proessing on the selected text. https://github.com/rioj7/regex-text-gen

Comment: `CTRL + SHIFT + L` helped